# Delphi pdf generate - pagination

Tags: delphi, pdf, pagination

What library (Debenu,Gnostic,other?) allow me to  read text from database nad then insert it to pdf file,but with  pagination ? For example I have 1000 rows in database,but one A4 page fit for example only 250 rows  so I need 4 pages, not one with small font...

Is it possible to mesure height of text before send it to pdf  ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Gnostice eDocEngine, then you can use the AutoPaginate property of the PDF engine to automatically create extra pages. You read the records from the database using regular Delphi classes, and then start writing to a page in the PDFEngine, when you start running out of space in a page, the PDFEngine will automatically spawn a new page and accommodate your textout. You can choose any page size.

[image]

This example has been taken directly from the help file.

```delphi
{
  This example illustrates autopagination and the use of
  built-in and custom placeholders.

  Drag a button component and a PDF engine component
  on a form. Double-click the button and use the
  following code for the click-event procedure.
}

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 i: Integer;
begin

  with gtPDFEngine1 do begin
    FileName := 'autopagination_placeholders_demo.pdf';
    Font.Size := 16;
    Font.Name := 'Times New Roman';
    TextFormatting.LineSpacing := 2;

    // Enable autopagination
    AutoPaginate := true;

    // Ensure all text placeholders are replaced at run-time
    Preferences.CalculateVariables := true;

    // Render pages after processing all instructions
    Preferences.ProcessAfterEachPage  // Required for generating values
         := false;                    // for built-in placeholders

    // Specify event handler for placeholder substitution events
    OnCalcVariables := gtPDFEngine1CalcVariablesEventHandler;

    BeginDoc;
    for i := 1 to 50 do begin
      // Render paragraph containing built-in and custom placeholders
      BeginPara;
      Textout('Hello, world! - on page #' +
              CphPageNo + ' of ' + CphTotalPages +
              ' - Random #<%my_random_number_placeholder%>');
      EndPara;
    end;
    EndDoc;
  end;
  Close;

end;

// Event handler that gets called whenever a placeholder is substituted.
procedure TForm3.gtPDFEngine1CalcVariablesEventHandler(
                      Sender: TgtCustomDocumentEngine;
                      Variable: String;
                      var Value: String);
begin
  // Provide a value for the custom placeholder
  if Variable = 'my_random_number_placeholder' then begin
    Value := FloatToStr(Random);
  end;
end;
```